# Is it possible ( or advisable) to allow open access to the new theme customizer for potential clients?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, theme-customizer

I've been using the [new theme customizer](http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/) and it really has me thinking how awesome it would be to allow potential theme buyers/clients etc to play with the customizer for a demo theme (without being logged in). The customizer is located at :

`..wp-admin/customize.php`.

So what it would take would be to somehow allow open access to this URL **but** nothing else in the back end. I suppose there is probably a security issue with this but I thought I'd get a discussion going on it here in case it's possible to do this safely as I'm sure other people might have the same idea.

So the question is : is there any safe way to allow open access to a single page of the admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea:

1. Make a user called 'Guest' and look up the user ID
2. When redirecting your potential clients to the admin page, redirect to a script that's logging in your clients as the guest user (Code #1)
3. Add an WordPress action to disallow the user when logged in as 'Guest' and not on customize.php (Code #2)

## Code #1

```
$creds = array(
    'user_login' => 'guest_user',
    'user_password' => 'guest_user_plain_password'
);

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
    echo $user->get_error_message();
else
    wp_redirect( 'your_absolute_admin_url' ); exit;
```

## Code #2

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_guest_user' );

function check_guest_user() {
    // Only when in backend and the guest user is logged in
    if ( is_admin() && user_id = get_current_user_id() ) {
        // Block other pages then custom.php
        global $pagenow;

        if ( 'customize' != $pagenow )
            exit();
    }
}

// replace user_id with the user ID of 'Guest'
```

Only problem with this script is when multiple users are trying the customizer. Saving customization settings per user would make things a lot harder.

It answers your question though, as it is a solution to give access to users to a specific page without them having to register an account.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

Comment: Thanks, yes you've answered the quesion alright, and I understand the concept. I actually had completely forgotteh about this question, and I don't have time to test this right now ... but it sounds like you have yourself, and I'm sure it would work or at least be made to work so I think your answer deserves the tick mark ... thanks.